# auto scroll in scrollview with speed

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to auto-scroll lyrics on my app using ScrollView with speed control button. I have tried to animate the scrolling, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For normal scrolling just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your code.